# transform a dataframe from long to wide in r, but needs date transformation

Tags: r, long-integer, reshape

I have a dataframe like this (each "NUMBER" indicate a student):

```
NUMBER  Gender  Grade Date.Tested   WI  WR  WZ
1       F       4     2014-02-18    6   9   10
1       F       3     2014-05-30    9   8   2
2       M       5     2013-05-02    7   9   15
2       M       4     2009-05-21    5   7   2
2       M       5     2010-04-29    9   1   4
```

I know I can use:

```
cook <- reshape(data, timevar= "?", idvar= c("NUMBER","Gender"), direction = "wide")
```

to change it into a wide format. However, I want to remove the date.tested to the times (1st time, 2nd time...etc), and indicate the grade.

What I want at the end is like this:

```
NUMBER  Gender Grade1 Grade 2 Grade 3 WI1  WR1  WZ1  WI2  WR2  WZ2 WI3  WR3  WZ3
1       F       3      4       NA     9    8     2   6      9   10   NA   NA   NA
```

and for the rest "NUMBER"s.

I have searched a lot but did not find an answer. Can someone help me with it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Some numbers in the expected output not seem to be correct.  For example `Grade2` as 5. Should't it be 3?  Also, not clear about how you want the `Date.Tested`.  Can you provide the whole expected output based on the input data instead of just one line?

Comment: @akrun I have corrected my output. I really really appreciate your help. This is a urgent task and I will try your code now. Thank you very much! Akrun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 data$id <- with(data, ave(seq_along(NUMBER), NUMBER, FUN=seq_along))
 reshape(data, idvar=c('NUMBER', 'Gender'), timevar='id', direction='wide')
```

If you want the `Date.Tested` variable to be included in the 'idvar' and you need only the 1st value for the group ('NUMBER' or 'GENDER')

```
 data$Date.Tested <- with(data, ave(Date.Tested, NUMBER,
                           FUN=function(x) head(x,1)))
 reshape(data, idvar=c('NUMBER', 'Gender', 'Date.Tested'), 
                timevar='id', direction='wide')
```

Comment: I think they would like to seq_along the NUMBER variable so

data$id <- with(data, ave(seq_along(NUMBER), NUMBER, FUN=seq_along))

Comment: @Jason Based on the input data, this will be the same.  I am a bit confused about the 'Date.Tested' as the OP seems to want it to be included in the `idvar'.  May be he wants to take the 1st date value.  Anyway, it is not clear.

Comment: I agree and I think it is a great answer. I'm just wondering if they want to identify by changes in the Gender variable or the NUMBER variable...

Comment: @Jason Thanks, may be you are right, the GENDER variable will be repeated, but NUMBER will be increased  in the original dataset.  The input example is confusing.